# how can i remove debug in outpot intellij

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, junit

I am using IntelliJ to build a telegram bot when I added testing to the code something weird happened I can't see  the application output anymore and all I see is this:
the build tool is maven

----update---
I found out that its problem with my dependency

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b038.png)

---dependency----

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jtelegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtelegrambotapi-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Do you see the application output in the Run tool window? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-tool-window.html

Comment: this is the run tool window I want to see only the application input

Comment: Please, add your solution to answers if possible.